# on rover project sqr killing program

Tags: c++, pythagorean

I am working on a project wherein I have a function that keeps killing my program.

I am doing work with arrays and have to use the pythagorean theorem to find the distance between two objects on a grid system.

Here is the function:

```
void Rover::check_if_collision(Rover arg[]) const{
    for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++){
        for (int n = 0; n <= 4; n++){
            if (arg[i].name == arg [n].name){
                n++;
            }
            if (arg[i].xpos == arg[n].xpos && arg[i].ypos == arg[n].ypos){
                cout << "Alert! " << arg[i].name << "ran into "
                        << arg[n].name << endl;
            }
        }            
    }
}​
```

I don't know what is killing the program.

Comment: Looks like a job for the debugger. What Development Environment are you using?

Comment: The `<=` in a `for` loop is often dangerous. It allows entry on the maximum value which is typically out of range in an array. If `arg` is arg[4], onlu 0 through 3 are allowed indexes, so `i <= 4` will run off the end.

Comment: Next, you have an `n++` in the body of the inner `for` loop that may push `n` out of the valid range.  Consider ditching the array in favour of [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) or [std::array](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) and [use iterators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterator).

Comment: I definitely suspect that you are running off the end of your arg array.  As @user4581301 pointed out above, the <= construct is a red flag.  You don't specify the extent of that array, so there is no way to know for sure by simple inspection.  Also I note the n++ on line 5 could push you out of bounds in the very next if statement if n is already the index of the last array element.

Comment: Anyway, not enough code here to do more than guess as possible problems.

Comment: No sign of Pythagoras here.

Comment: Just saw @user4581301's follow-up to his first comment.  I think iterators are a good idea but seeing as to how this is a learning assignment for you, I also think it would be a worthwhile learning experience to use the debugger, step through your code (it cannot have that many execution steps before trouble begins) and understand why it is failing and how to fix it the way it is.  This exercise would sharpen your debugging skills and make you see the reason for iterators, et. al.

Comment: I got it to work by modifying the if statement to be

Comment: if (arg[n] != arg[i]) and encasing the whole for loop in that